# Issue with javascript functions' bind method

Tags: javascript

I was surprised about the behavior of the following script, when executed in Chrome's js console:

```
var me = { name: 'John'};

function theFunc(){
 console.log(this);
}

theFunc.bind(me);

theFunc();//this is window???
```

I was expecting the bind function call to bind to the object literal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bind()` returns a **new** function, that must then be set to a variable to be saved.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```js
var me = { name: 'John'};

function theFunc(){
 console.log(this);
}

theFunc = theFunc.bind(me);

theFunc();
```

Comment: Mine uses a Stack Snippet. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need call (*assign it to variable*) function like this

```
theFunc = theFunc.bind(me);

theFunc();
```

> *The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its*
>   *this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of*
>   *arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.*

[.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

[Example](http://jsbin.com/wubeci/1/edit?js,output)

P.S. In our case you also can use `call` or `apply`, like this

```
var me = { name: 'John'};

function theFunc(){
 console.log(this);
}

// theFunc.call(me); or

theFunc.apply(me);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/buxibi/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander! +1

Comment: ​+1 for mentioning `call` and `apply`.